# Create an array from each column of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a 14 x 13 matrix of doubles and I need to loop through this matrix and save each column into a separate one-dimensional array.

Currently I have the following code:

```
for i = 1:14
     for j = 1:13
     if i == 1
        A(1, j) = M(1, j)
     elseif i == 2
        B(1, j) = M(2, j) ...
     end
   end
 end
```

This works only for the first row and I don't see how conceptually this would be correct. I don't think you need to create a separate array manually...

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) to convert this so that each column is a separate element in a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). Then if necessary you can assign them to different variables with [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html).

```
data = rand(14,13);
cellArray = num2cell(data, 1);

% And if you must assign them to variables.
[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M] = deal(cellArray{:});
```

Alternately, you can simply access the elements of `cellArray` rather than assigning them to variables.

```
value = cellArray{1};
size(value)

    14   1
```

If you can't use built-in functions your best bet is to use the colon operator to grab all rows for a given column.

```
A = data(:,1);
B = data(:,2);
```

You *definitely* don't want to use for loops if you can help it as they are notoriously slow in MATLAB.

That being said, it may be easier to keep your data as a matrix and then perform operations on the columns. A matrix is a much cleaner data structure than having a million different variables in your workspace. It really depends on what you're trying to do with it next.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use any built-in functions for that :( The assignment wants it to be done using for loops...

Comment: @Micard does it explicitly say for loops or just no built-in functions?

Comment: It doesn't say "use for loops" but I know the expectations. See, the way I showed in my code example works, but I wonder if there is a better way to do it. More procedural way.

Comment: @Micard I have updated my post with a solution not using built-in functions. This is much preferred over for loops. While for loops are common in C their use is discouraged in MATLAB.